# Opengl instanced batching

Tags: opengl, geometry-instancing

Is there a way of drawing an instanced buffer in sections/batches?

Currently I am shoving all of my geometry into large vbos, generating a render script that batches models by shader/textures/atlases, then drawing by using `glDrawElements` with a count and an offset into the indices. All good.

I am thinking of moving to instancing to reduce the amount of data that needs to be transferred to the gpu but other than sending a bunch of offsets as instanced attributes I can't see an out-of-the-box way of doing this with an opengl draw call.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Instancing means drawing the same mesh multiple times. So unless all of these "batches" are using the same mesh, it's not especially helpful to you. Also, instancing doesn't "reduce the amount of data that needs to be transferred to the gpu." If you were sending transforms for each object before, you still need to send transforms for each object afterwards. You're just sending them through a different mechanism (vertex buffers instead of uniforms), but the principle is the same.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Yes I would be drawing the same quad multiple times but with a different transform each time - the potential save on transfer is because that transform only need be sent once per instance rather than once per vertex.

Comment: Instancing quads is not a good idea. There's not enough data in a quad to gain much from it. You'd probably be better off just doing the local quad transform on the CPU and uploading that to the GPU.

Comment: I'm writing a gui where each element has a (potentially rotated) clipping box - rather than doing everything cpu side and having to write a clipping algorithm (non-trivial) I would rather send the local transform, the clipping rect and the parent transform to the gpu, let opengl do the clipping against an axis aligned clip box and then apply the parent transform. Sending all this data for every vertex would be hideous though which is why I thought of instancing. Looks like that's a bit of a dead-end too though.